# OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space. How can I fix this error that happens in a recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a Java application that parses pdf files in a directory and its subdirectories and creates a database using the information found in the files.

Everything was fine when I was using the program on around 900 files or so (which create a SQLite database with multiple tables, some of wihch contain 150k rows).

Now I'm trying to run my program on a larger set of data (around 2000 files) and at some point I get "OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap space". I changed the following line in my jdev.conf file:

```
AddVMOption  -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

to 512M and I got the same error (though later, I think). I'm going to change it to something bigger again, but the thing is the computers this program will be used on are much older and thus don't have as much memory. Normally, the users are not going to add more than 30 files at a time, but I want to know at how many files I'm supposed to limit them to. Ideally, I'd like my program not to throw an error regardless of how many files are to be parsed.

At first, I thought it was my SQLite queries that were causing the error, but after reading up on Google, it's probably some recursive function. I isolated it (I think it's the correct one at least), to this function:

```
 public static void visitAllDirsAndFiles(File dir) {
      if(dir.isDirectory()) 
      {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) 
        {
          visitAllDirsAndFiles(new File(dir, children[i]));
        }
      }
      else
      {
        try
        {          
          BowlingFilesReader.readFile(dir);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
          exc.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Other Exception in file: " + dir);
        }
      }
  }
```

I think the problem might be that it recursively calls this function for each subsequent directory, but I'm really not sure that could be the problem. What do you think? If it might be, how can I make it so I don't get this error again? If you think it is impossible that this section alone causes the problem, I'll try to find which other part of the program can cause it.

The only other thing I can see causing that is that I connect to the database before calling the above method and I disconnect after it returns. The reason for that is that if I connect and disconnect after each file, my programs takes a lot longer to parse the data, so I'd really like not to have to change that.

Comment: PermGen space is not heap space. Did you copy and paste the wrong option, or did you increase the wrong option?

Comment: Oh, and BTW you can simplify the iteration syntax to `for (String s : children) { visitAllDirsAndFiles(new File(dir, s)); }`

Comment: Are you certain you do not have a memory leak in your program?

Comment: probably you forgot to close all I/O, and in finally block

Comment: Another approach, should it come to that, would be to write the routine such that it doesn't use recursion.

Comment: I feel kind of stupid now, but after everyone here telling me that it was not heap space and I might have a memory leak, I checked again to make sure I didn't have one and found one right away... Tell me if it might be related (probably is): when I was catching exceptions in BowlingFilesReader, I think my String reader and BufferedReader objects were not being closed properly (now I have put them in finally blocks). Could that be it? Exceptions are thrown when the files are badly formatted and we have to re-generate them.

Comment: @Marvo: if the recursion itself were the issue, the OP's code would throw a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @mrKorbel That's what happened I think. I found such an error in my program right when you were typing it, which confirms it was probably this. I'll run my program again and I'll come back when it's done running, thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: @Adam Smith then same way you have to close all Resulset, Prepare..., there are must exists example for that, JProfiler can shows all opened Object, don't forget that all there Object never gone from JVM UsedMemory, nor GC'ed

Comment: @Ihballoti, recursion itself (its effect on the call stack anyway) might not be the problem, but memory allocations in the repeated calls might blow the heap, even if the allocations were freed at the end of the recursive call.  If that's the case, doing the work serially might resolve that issue.

Comment: @mrKorbel The same problem happened... I'm going to close my ResultSets, PreparedStatements and Statements now, but can you explain why I have to close them? Don't they get de-allocated when the method returns (thus they're no longer in the scope of any methods)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the origin of the problem was recursion, you would get an error related to stack instead of heap. Seems that you have some kind of memory leak in `BowlingFilesReader`...

Comment: Yes, like I commented in the OP, after everyone told me it wasn't the recursion that was causing the error, I tried to find a leak and found that my readers were not getting closed properly when an Exception was thrown, so I put them in finally blocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

MaxPermSize will only change your permagen space.  You are running out of Heap space.  Increase your max heap size with -Xmx properties

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try increasing the heap space with something like

```
-mx1000m
```

If you have a 64-bit JVM you can use up to about 80% of the total memory of the machine. If you have a 32-bit JVM you may be limited to around 1200 to 1400 MB depending on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

`BowlingFilesReader.readFile(dir);` is suspicious. How much is it loading into memory, and why? If it's loading all files in a rather large directory into memory, that's an issue.

You also might try

`java -Xmx 1G` or more, depending on your RAM situation.

You could always try using a stack instead of a recursive function.

```
S = []
while( !S.isEmpty() ){
   S.pop()
   //operate
   S.push( all of the current item's children )
}
```

Comment: Variable dir is in fact a File when it gets to that line, so that's not the problem.. As for the stack, that's a great idea even if I just found that the recursion wasn't the problem. It's probably going to be more efficient than making a long-running recursive call.

Comment: Yup. Using a stack or queue instead of recursive function calls is a very common strategy in algorithms problem contests. Often the recursive functions will get far too deep far too fast for the kinds of data the problems require. Note that a queue would give you a BFS instead of a DFS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should download a copy of the Memory Analyzer Tool [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php). Once you have that take a heap dump, load it in MAT, run the Leak Suspect report and you should be able to find out rather quickly what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

@Adam Smith to your question(s)

```
The same problem happened... I'm going to close my ResultSets, 
PreparedStatements and Statements now, but can you explain 
why I have to close them? Don't they get de-allocated when 
the method returns (thus they're no longer in the scope of any methods)?
```

most Jave IDE has built-in JProfiler or available plugin, integrate your project, run with profiler and then you'll see all Objects which are presents in Runtime, nothing complicated

then you have to close:

[File I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) , [JDBC Introduction](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) (example on page's bottom), and to check and avoids to opening lots of Connections (not only JDBC Conn), create one and reuse that, if everything done you can Close this Conn too, (Connection is hard and slower action on both sides, on PC and Server too), all Streamed Object must be closed in [The finally Block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html), because always works

as I mentioned these Object never gone from JVM UsedMemory and majorities ... never are GC'ed (for more details search on this forum), GC never works immediatelly

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long total = runtime.totalMemory();
    long free = runtime.freeMemory();
    long max = runtime.maxMemory();
    long used = total - free;   
    System.out.println(Math.round(max / 1e6) + " MB available before Cycle");
    System.out.println(Math.round(total / 1e6) + " MB allocated before Cycle");
    System.out.println(Math.round(free / 1e6) + " MB free before Cycle");
    System.out.println(Math.round(used / 1e6) + " MB used before Cycle");
    //.... your code with 
    //.....
    runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long total = runtime.totalMemory();
    long free = runtime.freeMemory();
    long max = runtime.maxMemory();
    long used = total - free;
    System.out.println(Math.round(max / 1e6) + " MB available past Cycle");
    System.out.println(Math.round(total / 1e6) + " MB allocated past Cycle");
    System.out.println(Math.round(free / 1e6) + " MB free past Cycle");
    System.out.println(Math.round(used / 1e6) + " MB used past Cycle");        

    runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.gc();

    //dealyed with some Timer ... 
    long total = runtime.totalMemory();
    long free = runtime.freeMemory();
    long max = runtime.maxMemory();
    long used = total - free;
    System.out.println(Math.round(max / 1e6) + " MB available after GC");
    System.out.println(Math.round(total / 1e6) + " MB allocated after GC");
    System.out.println(Math.round(free / 1e6) + " MB free after GC");
    System.out.println(Math.round(used / 1e6) + " MB used after GC");
```

more infos on this forum and :-) described in English language :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, I'll keep that in mind and I'm sure it'll help me to not make the same mistakes again! I really appreciate your help!