# Java: how to speed up JTree reconstruction by reading data from mongodb (remote server)?

Tags: java, swing, mongodb, jtree

basically mongodb stores each node userobject(NodePro) with parentId.

This class recursively builds a Jtree from querying all the children of a given parentId.

The problem is I have to wait up to 5 minutes for the entire tree to load when dealing with hundreds or thousands of nodes of a single tree.

Is there a way to speed this up significantly? currently even dealing with under hundred nodes, it will take a long time for the tree to become complete.

```
public class BuildTree {

    public BuildTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode aParentNode = treeNode;
        try {
            processChildren(aParentNode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void processChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode) throws Exception{
        NodePro np = (NodePro) parentNode.getUserObject();      

        List<NodePro> nodelist = NodeDAO.getInstance().getChildrenOfParent(np.getId().toString());

        if (nodelist.isEmpty()){    
            System.out.println("empty");
            return;
        }else{

             for (int i=0; i< nodelist.size(); i++)
              {            

                 NodePro childnode = nodelist.get(i);
                 DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(childnode);

                 TreeModel.getInstance().insertNodeInto(child,parentNode,TreeModel.getInstance().getChildCount(parentNode));

                 DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) 
                    TreeModel.getInstance().getChild(parentNode, i);

                 processChildren(parent);
              }

            return;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What does the profiler tell you?

Comment: what profiler ? how do u check that?

Comment: E.g. JProfiler. Rn the project under the profiler and check where the time is wasted.

Comment: is there a free open source one that works with eclipse ide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@trashgod is right in his comment: where is the code spending its time? Is it in the object creation? `DefaultMutableTreeNode` doesn't perform well when you've got thousands of node to create. Is it during retrieval of the node information from MongoDB?

If you can't speed up the creation of the tree, you'll want to investigate lazily-loading the children of a node. That is, don't load the node until the user requests to see the children.

Other possibilities are to load the children nodes in a background thread.

However, like any performance improvement work, you need to measure which part of your code is slow and then figure out how to improve it.

Comment: +1 [`jvisualvm`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is handy. No sense optimizing the insertion if the acquisition is taking most of the time.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jvmmonitor.org/ as it's a basic profiler that works from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

that would be comment but

remove enless `MongoDb engine` in your topics, that nothing to do with your issue (and for number of your posts)

there are three areas

1/ you are not familair with (Abstract/Default) `TreeModel` correct and proper way, create `JTree` and its `Model` once, not as you displayed, then strictly separeted Swing `JComponets` and Bussines Logics (load/change/manage/save/whatever with data for Swing `JComponents`), your create new `void()` for any of your action

2/ issues with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), bacause anything from/to database is basically BackGroung Task, anything must be wrappef into `invokeLater()` and is is there `Custom Java Look and Feel` then into `invokeAndWait()`

3/ expands as @trashgod and @StanislavL correctly suggested carefully reads this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878720/outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-how-can-i-fix-this-error-that-happens-in-a-rec/6882154#6882154) about unclosed `JDBC Objects`